# SQL Query not fetching correct results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Can somebody please give me the correct query.

I have a table `Item` with two columns `ItemNo` and `AliasItemNo`.

I want to write a query to return me only those items that have more than one alias name

I'm trying to execute

```
select ItemNo, AliasItemNo 
from Item 
group by ItemNo, AliasItemNo 
having count(ItemNo) > 1 
order by ItemNo Asc
```

This query is not giving correct results.

Pls help

Answer (score 4):

A subquery with the count is the way that works in all rdbms:

```
SELECT ItemNo, AliasItemNo FROM Item i1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item i2 WHERE i1.ItemNo=i2.ItemNo) > 1
ORDER BY ItemNo Asc
```

In SQL-Server >= 2005 you could also use `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo)` in a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT ItemNo,AliasItemNo, 
    Num=COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo)
   FROM Item)
SELECT ItemNo, AliasItemNo FROM CTE
WHERE  Num > 1
ORDER BY ItemNo Asc;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78d9c/9/1

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select ItemNo
from Item 
group by ItemNo
having count(AliasItemNo) > 1 
order by ItemNo Asc
```

You are counting ItemNo instead of AliasItemNo

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Here's a couple of ways.

---

```
 --using a sub query
SELECT
    ItemNo,
    AliasItemNo
FROM
    Item INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                ItemNo
            GROUP BY
                ItemNo
            HAVING
                COUNT(AliasItemNo) > 1)
            AS dupes
        ON
            Item.ItemNo = dupes.ItemNo
ORDER BY
    Item.ItemNo ASC
```

---

```
 --using CTE
;WITH
dupes AS
(
    SELECT
        ItemNo
    GROUP BY
        ItemNo
    HAVING
        COUNT(AliasItemNo) > 1
)
SELECT
    ItemNo,
    AliasItemNo
FROM
    Item INNER JOIN dupes
        ON
            Item.ItemNo = dupes.ItemNo
ORDER BY
    Item.ItemNo ASC
```

---